# Angularjs Gettext Translate from mongodb database

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, localization, gettext, angular-gettext

I am using [Angularjs gettext](https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/) in my [AngularJS Full-Stack generator](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) Project.
It is working very good for static text.
But I need to capture data from the user in multi-language which I'll store in MongoDB database.
For MongoDB multilanguage schema, I used [mongoose-intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-intl).
Is there any way we can use gettext to translate data for dynamic text.

My MongoDB schema looks like following:

```
{
     _id: '...',
     name: {
         en: 'Name in english',
         de: 'Name in German',
         fr: 'Name in French'
     }
}
```